# init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'selected_facets

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to make a custom search form using django haystack,

my form:

```
class UserSearchForm(SearchForm):
    resume = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=resume.objects.all(),
required=False)

    def search(self):
        # To get a SQS that's already handled the main field.
        sqs = super(UserSearchForm, self).search()

        # Now handle searching for the school if that's been chosen.
        if 'resume' in self.cleaned_data:
            sqs = sqs.filter(resumes=self.cleaned_data['resume'])

        return sqs
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^search/$', FacetedSearchView(form_class=UserSearchForm, searchqueryset=sqs1), name='haystack_search'),
```

serach_indexes.py

```
class UserIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    city = indexes.CharField(model_attr='city')
    dob = indexes.CharField(model_attr='dob')
    first_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='first_name')
    last_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='last_name')
    phone_number1 = indexes.CharField(model_attr='phone_number1')
    phone_number2 = indexes.CharField(model_attr='phone_number2')
    phone_number3 = indexes.CharField(model_attr='phone_number3')
    cnic = indexes.CharField(model_attr='cnic')
    gender = indexes.CharField(model_attr='gender')
    resumes = indexes.MultiValueField()

    def prepare_resumes(self, obj):
        # Use the relation and hang the id's off it.
        return [resume.resume_id for resume in obj.resumes.all()] 

    def get_model(self):
        return user_info
```

when i go to the url it says '**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'selected_facets''

Actually what i want to do is when a user is searched then it return its info,education,experiences etc..i have separate models for all these.

Comment: Show your `SearchForm`.

Comment: SearchForm is the haystack form

Comment: First up check if your haystack version supports selected facets.
 
Which field are you faceting on? you simply pass along a faceted=True parameter on the fields you wish to facet on. Can you show where you used 'selected_facets' link.  This link might be helpful http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html#narrowing-the-search